# Вопрос по vueX как c actions получить значение state?

Tags: vuex

Уже попробовал и

```
const newUser = this.state.loginSearch
```

и

```
const newUser = this.$store.state.loginSearch
```

В итоге undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: async fetchUser({state}) {
const newUser = state.loginSearch
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как упомянул [@Genesis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352439/genesis) данные от стейта в vuex не беруться с помощью команды this, оно находится в объекте контекста (context), то есть `context.state` также и геттеры находятся внутри объекта контекста, более подробно про это можно тут прочитать: https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/actions.html

Comment: async fetchUsers(context) {
      console.log(newUser);
      const newUser = context.state.loginSearch

Comment: и все равно undefined(

Comment: Стоп, а почему ты проверяешь переменную ДО присваивания?

Comment: Да, только заметил)) Спасибо) Все работает)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Можешь ответ пометить галочкой, чтобы другие пользователи в будущем если столкнуться с такой проблемой быстро ее решили

Comment: да, конечно) Благодарю!)